# интервал для типа timestamptz - SQL postgre

Tags: postgresql

Есть у меня база в которой платежи с 2012 по 2020 года с типом данных timestamptz. Выглядит так этот тип : 2017-01-24 21:40:19

Мне нужно сделать выборку для платежей только 2015 года. Как правильно это написать?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (ТАБЛИЦА)
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM (ПОЛЕ С ДАТОЙ)) = 2015;
```

**Пример выполнения запроса. Используемый DateStyle: ISO, ymd.**
[image: Пример выполнения]

Описание функции [EXTRACT](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/functions-datetime#functions-datetime-extract)